# Cypher: Finding movies that haven't been rated yet by particular user

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have 3 movies in my Neo4J database:

```
CREATE (interpreter:Movie {title: 'The Interpreter', year : 2005})
CREATE (dogville:Movie {title: 'Dogville', year : 2003})
CREATE (railwayMan:Movie {title: 'The Railway Man', year : 2013})
```

Also there are users:

```
CREATE (maciej:Person {name: 'Maciej Ziarko', birthYear: 1989})
```

who rate movies:

```
CREATE (maciej)-[:RATED {stars : 4, comment : "I liked that movie!" }]->(interpreter);
```

It's easy to find movies rated by particular user using Cypher

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:RATED]->(movie:Movie)
WHERE person.name = 'Maciej Ziarko'
RETURN movie.title
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+
| movie.title       |
+-------------------+
| "The Interpreter" |
+-------------------+
1 row
```

But how can I find movies **NOT** yet rated by particular user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use something like:

```
MATCH (m:Movie) WHERE NOT (m)<-[:RATED]-() return m.title
```

In `WHERE` you can filter for non existing paths using `NOT`, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-filter-on-patterns-using-not

Comment: That's nice. I didn't realize that I can use relationship patterns in WHERE clause. Super. Thanks! :-) I need to study Neo4J docs more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did after reading Stefan's answer:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie), (person:Person)
WHERE person.name = 'Maciej Ziarko' 
     AND (NOT (movie:Movie)<-[:RATED]-(person:Person))
RETURN movie.title
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+
| movie.title       |
+-------------------+
| "Dogville"        |
| "The Railway Man" |
+-------------------+
2 rows
```