# Select nodes which lack a certain type of relationship

Tags: neo4j

I want to select all the nodes in the db that don't have a given relationship type with any other node.

Here's my db structure: I have user nodes that publish event nodes. The publish relationship is more specific, there are various types of relationships, say `type1` and `type2`.

How can I do quickly select all user nodes that have `type1` relationships with events but don't have `type2` relationshiops with events.

Here's the query I'm using now:

```
START u = node:users("*:*") 
MATCH (ev1)<-[r1:type1]-(u)-[r2?:type2]->(ev2) 
WHERE r2 IS NULL
RETURN u
```

The problem is r2 is an optional relationship. This makes the above query VERY slow, confirming what the neo4j docs say.

How can I improve this query's speed? Can I better model the data to improve the performance?

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cypher: Finding movies that haven't been rated yet by particular user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543957/cypher-finding-movies-that-havent-been-rated-yet-by-particular-user)

Comment: @StefanArmbruster I used the answer in the question you recommended and I got a 50% increase in query response type. Here's the query I used:
start u = node:users('*:*')
match (u)-[:type1]->()
where not (u)-[:type2]->()
return count(distinct(u))

Comment: @StefanArmbruster However, I now notice i'm not able to attach references to relationships/nodes in the `where not` construct. Ie. `...where not (u)-[r2:type2]->(ev2) ...` Issues this error: Unknown identifier `ev2`. Unknown identifier `r2`. Any solutions?

Comment: since you're matching for a non-existing path in `WHERE NOT` you cannot assign variable names to its parts (they don't exist). So go for where not (u)-[:type2]->(), which reads "filter u by those not having a outgoing relationship of type `type2`".

Comment: @Stefan Armbruster Yup, it makes sense! What I'm trying to do is check if a user has a relationship to a node that does not have certain properties. In this case I don't need the `where not` check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I've found is two fold depending on the use case. I had two:

1. Find all user nodes who have relationships of type `type1` but don't have relationships of type `type2`.

Two queries can solve this, one using `optional relationships` which neo4j's manual warns against using:

```
START u = node:users("some query")
MATCH (ev1)<-[r1:TYPE1]-(u)-[r2?:TYPE2]->(ev2)
WHERE r2 IS NULL
RETURN u
```

Or use the faster variant which employs filtering on patterns. [Docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-filter-on-patterns-using-not)

```
START u = node:users("some query")
MATCH (ev1)<-[r1:TYPE1]-(u)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:TYPE2]->()
RETURN u
```

1. Find all user nodes who have relationships of type `type1` but don't have relationships of type `type2` with nodes with certain properties.

   START u = node:users("some query")
   MATCH (ev1)<-[r1:TYPE1]-(u)-[r2:TYPE2]->(ev2)
   WHERE ev2.property = value
   AND r2.property = value
   RETURN u

Given that my question had a performance note to it, I'll add two advice to speed up the queries above:

- index as clever as possible in Lucene and move as many query conditions as possible from `WHERE` to the index query. All in an effort to reduce the number of starting nodes! Note! Heavy indexing reduces write performance. See [lucene docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) for available query syntax.
- use parametric queries so neo4j can cache the execution strategy of your queries. [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-parameters.html)

Comment: strong +1 on using parameterized cypher. Indexing trades always write performance for read performance. So "index as much as possible" sounds a little bit misleading, it should be "index as clever as possible" to reduce the potential number of start nodes.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Modified! 10x